# How to avoid hard-coding database path using flask, SQLAlchemy, and declarative_base

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy suggests the [Declarative](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative) pattern for setting up a database connection. The example hard-codes a single database path, and it seems like I should avoid that, so that I can configure different databases for unit testing, local development, and then eventually production.

this is their database.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import yourapplication.models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid hard-coding this db path.

### Environment variables:

I could just replace the `sqlite:///....` path with an environment variable. But that would require some way to have `pytest` run with one set of environment vars and `flask run` use a different set. I'd much rather have my unit tests keep track of their own temporary database.[2] I'd also like `create_app()` that creates the Flask app to take a database path that's a config variable.

### Import database.py within an application context

I thought I could replace the database path with `current_app.config['DB']`, and import the database within `with app.app_context()`. But the Model classes need to import Base, and I can't subclass Base within the application context. So when the models get loaded, they're loaded outside the application context and that throws runtime errors.

### So what's the right way to use declarative_base in a flask app with unit tests?

Thanks for your help!

[2]: If that's what I should do, then I can live with it. But it seems messy to be using env vars there, when I'm configuring a flask app with its own config vars too.

Comment: It is a long article and it is a part of a extensive tutorial, but the author is (IMHO) the best teacher of Flask: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure Main topics regarding your questuion: Application factory pattern and dot-env files

Comment: Thanks very much! That looks like helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved my question. Instead of using the declarative_base class factory:

database.py:

```
engine="someengine"
db_session=[make a session here]
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query
```

And having my models import Base,

I simply followed the pattern [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#configuration). In database.py, I create a dumb db with

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Then in **init**.py, in the create_app app factory, I can initialize the app with app config variables and initialize the db with the app.*

```
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    import site.models
    db.create_all()
```

Models inherit from database.py's `db.Model` class.

```
from site.database import db
class MyModel(db.Model)
```

I can access the database in pytest tests by wrapping tests in a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app({[testing config]}
    with app.app_context():
        g.db = db
        yield app
        g.db.session.remove()
        g.db.drop_all()
```

This is working for me now. That said, if you think I'm doing something wrong, let me know!

*I think the SQLAlchemy object, once initialized with `init_app`, stores pointers to values that only exist when there's an active application context? Is that right? That's why just calling `db` doesn't connect to the apps database, but calling `db` within the app context does.